# Send mail with nodemailer, Express and Angular

Tags: angularjs, express, nodemailer

I'm following this tutorial: https://github.com/SpaceG/NodeMailerForm

Although in my case, I am additionally using Angular. I have verified that the tutorial works correctly. The problem is that I get the following error when I hit the submit button.

[formImage](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7E5cN.jpg)

I must clarify that I do not get any error messages on the console.

form1.html

```html
<h3 class="text-center">¡Consigue tu seguro ahora!</h3>
<br>
<p class="bg-info" id="msg"></p>
<form ng-controller="repeatSeguros" id="emailForm" method="post" role="form">
    <div class="form-group">
        <select class="form-control form-control-lg" name="seguro">
                <option selected>Elije un seguro</option>
                <option>Seguro Auto</option>
                <option>Vida</option>
                <option>Hogar</option>
        </select>
    </div>        
    <div class="form-group">
        <input type="email" class="form-control form-control-lg" name="email" placeholder="E-mail" required="required">
    </div>

    <p class="">
        <input type="checkbox" checked class="mr-2"> He leído y aceptado los <a href="#">términos y condiciones</a> sobre el tratamiento de datos.
    
    </p>
    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary btn-block btn-lg" id="send">Quiero información</button> 
    
</form>

<script>

    $(function(){
      
    var fullUrl =  location.protocol+'//'+location.hostname+(location.port ? ':'+location.port: '');

      $("#send").click(function(){      
        var formData = $("#emailForm").serialize();
        $("#msg").text("Enviando requerimiento ...");
                  $.ajax({
                    url: fullUrl+'/send',
                      type: 'POST',
                        data: formData,
                              success: function(result) {
                                  $("#msg").empty().text(result);
                                    },
                              error: function(e) {
                                  $("#msg").empty().text("There is some error to send email, Error code:"+e.status +", Error message:"+e.statusText);
                        },
                  dataType: "html",
                  timeout: 60000
              });
            });
        });
        
</script>
```

server.js

```js
/*
Configuración envío de e-mail
*/
var http=require('http');
var express=require('express');
var nodemailer = require("nodemailer");
var bodyParser = require('body-parser')
var app=express();
var port = Number(process.env.PORT || 5000);
app.use(bodyParser.json()); // to support JSON-encoded bodies
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: true }));

app.use('/', express.static(__dirname + '/'));


var path = require('path');

// Home page
app.all('/*',function(req, res, next){
    res.sendFile('index.html', { root: __dirname });
        //console.log 
        console.log('NodeMailer reading console log...' + req.url);
});

 
// sending mail function
app.post('/send', function(req, res){
if(req.body.email == "" || req.body.seguro == "") {
  res.send("Error: Email & Seguro should not blank");
  return false;
}

   // Sending Emails with SMTP, Configuring SMTP settings

    var smtpTransport = nodemailer.createTransport({
            host: "smtp.gmail.com", // hostname
            secureConnection: true, // use SSL
            port: 465, // port for secure SMTP
            secure: true,
            auth: {
                 user: '************@gmail.com',
                 pass: '*********'
            }
        });
        var mailOptions = {
            from: 'Lorem ipsum <*********@gmail.com>', // sender address
            to: '*********@*********.com, *********@*********.com', //+ req.body.email, // list of receivers
            subject: 'Lorem ipsum - Lorem ipsum', // Subject line
            //text: "Hello world ✔", // plaintext body
            html:
                'XXX: <br><br>' + 
                'XXX: ' + req.body.seguro + '<br>' + 
                'XXXX: ' + req.body.email
        }
        smtpTransport.sendMail(mailOptions, function(error, response){
        if(error){
             res.send("Email could not sent due to error: "+error);
        }else{
             res.send("Requerimiento enviado con éxito");
        } 
    }); 
});
 
// Starting server
var server = http.createServer(app).listen(port, function() {
console.log("Server is Running on 127.0.0.1:" + port);

});
```

index.html

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
    <title>Previsora - Corredores de Seguro</title>

    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="node_modules/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="custom.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="fonts/siloSoft.css">



</head>
<body ng-app="previsoraApp">
    
    <div ng-include='"views/header.html"'></div>
    <div class=""><ui-view></ui-view></div>
    <div ng-include='"views/footer.html"'></div>


    
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="node_modules/popper.js/dist/umd/popper.min.js"></script>
    <script src="node_modules/bootstrap/dist/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

    <script src="node_modules/angular/angular.min.js"></script>
    <script src="node_modules/angular-ui-router/release/angular-ui-router.min.js"></script>

    <script src="app.js"></script>


    
</body>
</html>
```

app.js

```js
var myApp = angular.module('previsoraApp', ['ui.router']);

myApp.config(function($stateProvider) {

    var inicio = {
        name: 'inicio',
        url: '/',
        templateUrl: 'views/inicio.html'
    }

    var seguroPersonas= {
        name: 'seguroPersonas',
        url: '/seguroPersonas',
        templateUrl: 'views/seguroPersonas.html'
    }

    var seguroEmpresas= {
        name: 'seguroEmpresas',
        url: '/seguroEmpresas',
        templateUrl: 'views/seguroEmpresas.html'
    }

    var nosotros= {
        name: 'nosotros',
        url: '/nosotros',
        templateUrl: 'views/nosotros.html'
    }

    var contacto= {
        name: 'contacto',
        url: '/contacto',
        templateUrl: 'views/contacto.html'
    }

    //Seguros Personas

    var salud= {
        name: 'salud',
        url: '/salud',
        templateUrl: 'views/segurosPersonas/salud.html'
    }

    var auto = {
        name: 'auto',
        url: '/auto',
        templateUrl: 'views/segurosPersonas/auto.html'
    }

    var hogar = {
        name: 'hogar',
        url: '/hogar',
        templateUrl: 'views/segurosPersonas/hogar.html'
    }

    var vida = {
        name: 'vida',
        url: '/vida',
        templateUrl: 'views/segurosPersonas/vida.html'
    }

    var educacion = {
        name: 'educacion',
        url: '/educacion',
        templateUrl: 'views/segurosPersonas/educacion.html'
    }

    var soatVehicular = {
        name: 'soatVehicular',
        url: '/soatVehicular',
        templateUrl: 'views/segurosPersonas/soatVehicular.html'
    }

    var soatMotos = {
        name: 'soatMotos',
        url: '/soatMotos',
        templateUrl: 'views/segurosPersonas/soatMotos.html'
    }


    //Seguros Empresas

    var multiriesgo = {
        name: 'multiriesgo',
        url: '/multiriesgo',
        templateUrl: 'views/segurosEmpresas/multiriesgo.html'
    }

    var vehiculares = {
        name: 'vehiculares',
        url: '/vehiculares',
        templateUrl: 'views/segurosEmpresas/vehiculares.html'
    }

    var transporte = {
        name: 'transporte',
        url: '/transporte',
        templateUrl: 'views/segurosEmpresas/transporte.html'
    }

    var trec = {
        name: 'trec',
        url: '/trec',
        templateUrl: 'views/segurosEmpresas/trec.html'
    }

    var sctr = {
        name: 'sctr',
        url: '/sctr',
        templateUrl: 'views/segurosEmpresas/sctr.html'
    }

    var vidaLey = {
        name: 'vidaLey',
        url: '/vidaLey',
        templateUrl: 'views/segurosEmpresas/vidaLey.html'
    }

    var empleados = {
        name: 'empleados',
        url: '/empleados',
        templateUrl: 'views/segurosEmpresas/empleados.html'
    }

    //Vistas
    $stateProvider.state(inicio);
    $stateProvider.state(seguroPersonas);
    $stateProvider.state(seguroEmpresas);
    $stateProvider.state(nosotros);
    $stateProvider.state(contacto);

    //Seguros Personas
    $stateProvider.state(salud);
    $stateProvider.state(auto);
    $stateProvider.state(hogar);
    $stateProvider.state(vida);
    $stateProvider.state(educacion);
    $stateProvider.state(soatVehicular);
    $stateProvider.state(soatMotos);

    //Seguros Empresas
    $stateProvider.state(multiriesgo);
    $stateProvider.state(vehiculares);
    $stateProvider.state(transporte);
    $stateProvider.state(trec);
    $stateProvider.state(sctr);
    $stateProvider.state(vidaLey);
    $stateProvider.state(empleados);
});
```